# jwt token giving invalid token error on deplying to azure web app but working on localhost

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

[image]

My question is that i have a web api which when on localhost is getting the result but when the same api is deployed on azure web app it is giving unauthorized error. what might be the reason?

Comment: can you post the console log from postman here.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

I created an Azure AD application for Azure App Service and added **API permissions** like below:

[image]

After granting the API permissions, I generated **access token** with parameters like below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

[image]

***By using the above access token, I am able to call the API successfully like below:***

`https://YourApp.azurewebsites.net/WeatherForecast`

[image]